# How to type LINE SEPARATOR character?

Tags: macos, keyboard, character, special-characters

I want to type the content along with line separator character ( \u2028 ), how to type this character from MAC keyboard.

Thanks.

Comment: There is a way (on OS X 10.11.5 at the very least); I came here hoping to find the key combination.  I occasionally end up with U+2028 Line Separator characters in my code when I'm typing too quickly, but haven't been able to discover what key combination it is that produces these.

Comment: Side-note: This question seems better suited for, and might be more likely to get a response on the Ask Different Stack Exchange.